# Filtering 2 vectors

Tags: android-layout

I'm trying to advanced filter 2 vectors based on what they have.

I want to sort through both of them and add the value which is in vector2 but not in vector1 to another string of vectors. So using the above example I want a 3rd vector to contain ["1"] which should be a string as it is in vector2 but not in vector1.

This is my code but it doesn't work ?

```
bool contains =false;
for (auto item : vector1) {
 if (item == vector2[i]) {
  contains = true
}
}
 if(contains){
   ...
```

Comment: `3rd_vector` is an invalid identifier because it begins with a digit.

Comment: Desperation not really being a factor, your loops are also invoking undefined behavior. a vector of size `N` is indexible from `0..(N-1)` inclusively. Using `for(int i=0;i<=xbarl.size();i++)` to enumerate `xbar1[i]` and `for(int j=0;j<=fvalues.size();j++)` to enumerate `fvalues[j]` *both* invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Read what I said, then understand that `i<=xbarl.size()` and `j<=fvalues.size()` are both problems, and should be `i<xbarl.size()` and `j<fvalues.size()` respectively.

Comment: @WhozCraig I did it but the last_vector now contains `["3","3","2","2","1","1","1","4","4"]`, I just need it to contain `["1"]`

Comment: That's a broken algorithm. Explain your code to yourself, *exactly* as it operates, step by step, and you'll see where it is broken. But your crash should at least be fixed.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Or simply sitting down and thinking through the logic of your loops? You have a logical error.

Comment: Posted an answer. I don't know what a "long time" is, but it must be different in my book than yours.

Comment: The vectors in your example are sorted; are the sorted by your requirements?